# Restoring the exact angle from std::cos(angle) using std::acos

Tags: c++, std, precision, numerical-stability

Is it guaranteed by the C++ standard that `angle == std::acos(std::cos(angle))` if `angle` is in the range [0, Pi], or in other words is it possible to restore the exact original value of `angle` from the result of `std::cos` using `std::acos` given the mentioned range limit?

The marginal cases when `angle` is `infinity` or `NaN` are omitted.

Comment: I don't think so. floating point precision prevents that.

Comment: You are limited by precision and rounding

Comment: The standard cannot make that guarantee. Simply because the result of `std::cos` may not be representable exactly by a `double`, so you get a truncation error, which will affect the result of `std::acos`.

Comment: Can I get an exact answer for floating point operations on arbitrary data?  No.

Comment: Ignoring the rounding issue, there are multiple angles that give the same `cos(angle)` (one every 2pi radians), so it would not be possible for `acos` to return to the same one.

Comment: Are there any limits on `angle`?

Comment: Even if the angle is in the range `[-2 * M_PI, 2 * M_PI]`, it isn't a question of mathematics, but of hardware and numeric constraints. This is a good read on the subject https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer by StoryTeller:

> The standard cannot make that guarantee, simply because the result of `std::cos` may not be representable exactly by a `double`, so you get a truncation error, which will affect the result of `std::acos`.

Comment: Is that actually the reason?  Is it impossible to make a conforming implementation that would map the value back to the initial value?

Comment: @StoryTeller: If it's a dupe then okay don't answer, but if you _are_ going to answer, please do so in the proper place!

Comment: @xaxxon, I'm afraid not. When the function accepts a value, it must treat every digit as significant, and the value as exactly what the caller intended to pass.

Comment: as defined here in 7.3.5.1 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I really hate having to type an answer just to have the question closed in an instant. This comment is just my two cents.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, Well it's relevant if the OP wants to rely on `angle == std::acos(std::cos(angle))` always being true, which is of course impossible.

Answer (score 3):

From cppreference.com:

> **”** If no errors occur, [acos returns] the arc cosine of arg (arccos(arg)) in the range [0 ; π]

In degrees, that's 0 to 180, inclusive, corresponding to cosine values 1 down through -1, inclusive.

Outside that range you can't even get an approximate correspondence. Computing the cosine *discards* information about which angle you had outside of that range. There's no way to get that information back.

How information is discarded:

First, in degrees, cos(x) = cos(K*360 + x), for arbitrary integer K. Secondly, cos(x) = cos(-x). This adds up to an awful lot of angle values that produce the same cosine value.

Also, even though all readers likely know this, but for completeness: since sines are cosines are very irrational numbers, generally not simple fractions, you can't expect exact results except for maybe cosine 1, which corresponds to 0 degrees.

Comment: @xaxxon: pi is little bit irrational, but not much, because it becomes a very systematic, simple sequence of digits when expressed in the factorial numeral system. But the sine of 1.234 degrees, uh oh, that's *very* irrational. :-p

Answer (score 1):

According to the standard:

> This International Standard imposes no requirements on the accuracy
>   of floating-point operations; see also 18.3.2. — end note ]

http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4606.pdf

Comment: True, but the reason is to avoid constraining the implementation from using the full power of the hardware. And I think it's irrelevant. Even *if* a machine existed that could do exact computations every time, the standard cannot make that promise. From a practical standpoint, one should always be careful when dealing with numeric code.

Comment: @StoryTeller The question specifically asked if the standard made the guarantee and I think this bit in the standard very specifically precludes the guarantee which is why I added it as an answer -- because I think approaches the answer from the direction requested in the question.

Comment: I think it's a bit of stretch reading that from this quote. The standard usually tries to be as little limiting as possible. But yeah, I can see why it *could* preclude it.

Comment: @StoryTeller  It precludes the standard making the guarantee because they would be mutually exclusive.  I wasn't trying to say it precludes an implementation that does so -- but  that's not the question posed.

Comment: I see. A rare occasion when a negative claim is provable :)

Comment: @StoryTeller Well, you can just rephrase it.   Does the standard allow for sin(asin(x)) != x.   Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Even mathematically this is impossible. For example, `cos(2*PI)` is 0, but so is `cos(4*PI)`.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot the period the function.